# How to create dynamic instances of PyQT registered types in QML

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml

Building on the *Registering Python Types* at: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/qml.html I'd like to be able to instantiate instances of a registered Python type in QML dynamically.

E.g. define Person type:

```
class Person(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._name = ''

    @pyqtProperty('QString')
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name

# ...
qmlRegisterType(Person, 'People', 1, 0, 'Person')
```

Now inside QML, I'd like to say create a new Person object when a button is click for example:

```
import People 1.0

import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

// create application window etc.
// add a button
Button {
    text: "Ok"
    onClicked: {
        var p = new Person();
        p.name = 'Bob';
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. I thought Qt's createComponent function might be the way to go but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically instantiate qml objects by creating a component in the following ways:

```
function create_person(name){
    var p = Qt.createQmlObject("import People 1.0; Person{}", null, "createPerson")
    p.name = name
}
```

```
Button {
    text: "Ok"
    onClicked: var p = create_person("Bob")
}
```

Or

```
Component {
    id: person_provider
    Person{
    }
}
function create_person(name){
    var p = person_provider(null)
    p.name = name
}
Button {
    text: "Ok"
    onClicked: var p = create_person("Bob")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to instantiate it as if it were a javascript object. But that's not what it is. You created a QML object. So you have to instantiate it that way, like this:

```
import People 1.0
import QtQuick 2.7

Person {
    name: 'Bob'
}
```

If you want to create it dynamically, then you do that the QML way too:

```
function createPerson() {
    var qml = "import QtQuick 2.0; import People 1.0; Person { name: 'Bob' }";
    var personObj = Qt.createQmlObject(qml, parentObj, "createPerson");
}
```